# Blackout image except for polygons provided as coordinates in OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, opencv

I need to black out an image *except* for the polygons formed by provided coordinates.

For example:

```
./maskout_image.py --input input.jpg --coords "11,924 1255,934 1063,738, 216,711"
--coords "524,267 984,275 1276,910 69,926" 
--coords  "304,203 405,184 472,705 367,716"
```

There could be multiple such coords.

Each coord represents multiple polygon points (X/Y in pixels)

The openCV code should basically take input.jpg and mask out everything (blacken it out) that does *not* fall inside the areas formed by the supplied coordinates.

I am aware of OpenCV's polygon APIs, but I'm not sure how to do exclusion

Would appreciate some direction/help.

This is in Python.

Comment: 1) create a black mask, 2) draw filled polygons in white, 3) set the image to black where the mask is black, 4) done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you, @Miki and @Trigary for the hints. I wasn't thinking this right. Your approach worked. Final result:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# original image
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
contours = np.array ([[418,368], [885,365], [953,562], [361,569]])

mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, pts=[contours], color=(255,255,255))

# apply the mask
masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

# save the result
cv2.imwrite('image_masked.png', masked_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a mask from the provided coordinates: each polygon formed by the coordinates should be bitwise OR-d into a single Mat, the mask. When you have that mask, you can apply a simple bitwise AND onto the input image. This will leave only the regions covered by the polygons.

How to draw polygons:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillconvexpoly

How to use bitwise operations:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html