# Blackout part of an image of specified coordinates python cv2

Tags: python, opencv

My question is the opposite of the following stackoverflow question:
[Blackout image except for polygons provided as coordinates in OpenCV (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54466916/blackout-image-except-for-polygons-provided-as-coordinates-in-opencv-python)

I want only a certain part of my image to be blacked out.

Comment: Invert the `mask` with `mask = 255 - mask`, then `AND` it as the post shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @stateMachine for mentioning about the inverting of mask.

Further beyond that, the cv2.fillPoly function should set the color to [0,0,0]

These are the parts I changed

```
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
mask = 255 - mask

cv2.fillPoly(mask, pts=[contours], color=(0,0,0))
```